Re-reading messages from the topic
When a new application instance is launched, the messages are read again
I have a spring boot application deployed in Openshift, on 2 pods, it listens to a specific topic
Listener settings:
    @KafkaListener(topics = "test_topic",
            containerFactory = "testFactory",
            autoStartup = "true")
    public void getMessage(@Payload Message message) {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> testFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                                                                                          Configurator configurator) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(configurator, kafkaProperties));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(500);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("test-module");
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(60000);
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory(Configurator configurator,
                                                            KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        kafkaProperties.getConsumer().setMaxPollRecords(500);
        kafkaProperties.getConsumer().setAutoOffsetReset("latest");
        kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getProperties().put(MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class));
    }

I came across this situation:
3 messages were produce in the topic, the application on the 1st pod - subtracted No. 1 and No. 3, on the 2nd pod - No. 2
Then another pod rose and the application in it read all 3 messages again
How can this be? All listners are in one consumerGroup and the messages are committed, I don’t see any problems with the settings

That is possible, if new consumer comes with a new groupId. Please, investigate Kafka broker logs to be sure what groups are subscribed to that topic.
